# how to use tencoding's getstring with a part of static array w/o block copying

Tags: arrays, delphi, static, character-encoding, getstring

I'm trying to apply Tencoding.UTF8.Getstring on a part of a static bytes array without copying its content to a dynamic array. If the array is dynamic, i have no problem using:

```
stringvar:=Tencoding.utf8.Getstring(dynbytearray,offset,length);
```

however, when i have a static predefined length array, the syntax doesn't work and all i could figure is to declare a new dynamic array, set its length, and copy the bytes. I don't like doing the needless copying since i suspect i just miss a syntax trick. My attempts like "setlength(*newdynarr*,whatever); *newdynarr*:=@*staticarr* [optional offset]" failed so far. Thanks.

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: RAD Studio 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public `TEncoding.GetString()` method only supports dynamic arrays, but you can use the protected `PByte` overloads of [`TEncoding.GetCharCount()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetCharCount) and [`TEncoding.GetChars()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetChars) instead, eg:

```
type
  TEncodingHelper = class(TEncoding)
  public
    function GetString(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): String;
  end;

function TEncodingHelper.GetString(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): String;
begin
  SetLength(Result, GetCharCount(Bytes, ByteCount));
  GetChars(Bytes, ByteCount, PChar(Result), Length(Result));
end;

var
  S: string;
begin 
  S := TEncodingHelper(TEncoding.UTF8).GetString(PByte(@arr[index]), ByteCount);
end;
```

Or:

```
type
  TEncodingHelper = class helper for TEncoding
  public
    function GetString(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): String;
  end;

function TEncodingHelper.GetString(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): String;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Self.GetCharCount(Bytes, ByteCount));
  Self.GetChars(Bytes, ByteCount, PChar(Result), Length(Result));
end;

var
  S: string;
begin 
  S := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(PByte(@arr[index]), ByteCount);
end;
```

Comment: Thx, works for now (tested with plain english only). Will comment later if i encounter problems with messy unicode i need to examine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars). For instance like this:

```
uses
  SysUtils, SysConst, Windows;

function Utf8BytesToString(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): string;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := UnicodeFromLocaleChars(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, Pointer(Bytes),
    ByteCount, nil, 0);
  if (ByteCount>0) and (Len=0) then begin
    raise EEncodingError.CreateRes(@SNoMappingForUnicodeCharacter);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  UnicodeFromLocaleChars(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, Pointer(Bytes),
    ByteCount, Pointer(Result), Len);
end;
```

The `System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars` function wraps `MultiByteToWideChar` on Windows and `UnicodeFromLocaleChars` on POSIX systems. The `TEncoding` class makes use of `System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars` to perform its conversions. Should you wish to travel in the opposite direction there is `System.LocaleCharsFromUnicode`.

Comment: Undeclared identifier: 'UnicodeFromLocaleChars'. Perhaps i use a version too old (D2010).

Comment: @miodrag: `UnicodeFromLocaleChars()` and `LocalCharsFromUnicode()` were introduced in XE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you mean `MultiByteToWideChar()` instead, since the OP is converting *from* UTF-8 *to* UTF-16.

Comment: actually my data is very messy and i examine it manually first to determine if it's ansi or utf8 or unicode with or without bom (and which order), so i need to set the encoding myself.

Comment: As I'm sure you know it's not possible to detect encoding perfectly. Even so you can perfectly well pass the encoding to MultiByteToWideChar once you have detected it.